# How to start H2 WebServer using Spring without XML?

Tags: java, spring, h2

I am currently using all Spring configurations as annotation and I would like to translate the following to it:

```
<bean id="h2Server" class="org.h2.tools.Server" factory-method="createTcpServer" init-method="start" destroy-method="stop" depends-on="h2WebServer">
    <constructor-arg value="-tcp,-tcpAllowOthers,-tcpPort,9092"/>
</bean>
<bean id="h2WebServer" class="org.h2.tools.Server" factory-method="createWebServer" init-method="start" destroy-method="stop">
    <constructor-arg value="-web,-webAllowOthers,-webPort,8082"/>
</bean>
```

Using the above configuration works perfectly, but since I have nothing else configured using XMLs, I would like to change it as well.

Can anyone please help me with this issue?

EDIT: Using the answer provided, this is the end result:

```
@Bean(name = "h2WebServer", initMethod="start", destroyMethod="stop")
public org.h2.tools.Server h2WebServer() throws SQLException {
    return org.h2.tools.Server.createWebServer("-web", "-webAllowOthers", "-webPort", "8082");
}


@Bean(initMethod="start", destroyMethod="stop")
@DependsOn(value = "h2WebServer")
public org.h2.tools.Server h2Server() throws SQLException {
    return org.h2.tools.Server.createTcpServer("-tcp", "-tcpAllowOthers", "-tcpPort", "9092");
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can rewrite your XML bean definitions using the `@Bean` annotation style in Java, as documented in [Java-based container configuration](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.13.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-java).

For example:

```
@Bean(init-method="start", destroy-method="stop")
public org.h2.tools.Server h2WebServer() {
   return org.h2.tools.Server.createWebServer(
      "-web", "-webAllowOthers", "-webPort", "8082"
   )
}
```

The doc link above will show you how to wire your two beans together, and how to add it to the Spring context.

Comment: Thank you very much! Using your example and the link provided I was able to make it work.